# Finding Substring with Different Ending

Tags: sql, regex, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to find the substring of a list of URLs but having trouble due to an extra character (forward slash) at the end of one of the URL. Below are two examples of the data:

- [www.url1.com/test](http://www.url1.com/test)
- [www.url1.com/test2/](http://www.url1.com/test2/)

I'd like to get the last string of the URL--in this case `test` and `test2`. However, my current `REGEX_SUBSTR` is only giving me the substring of the first URL and a null for the second URL since the second URL has a forward slash.

How do I create the query so that it returns both `test` and `test2`?

Sample of my `REGEXP_SUBSTR` query:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(URL, '/([^/]+)$', 1, 1, 'e', 1) as URL_EXTRACT
```

Comment: What about `www.url1.com/` or `www.url1.com`? Should it match anything? Or we don't have such records?

Comment: No, just need the last string of the URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [PARSE_URL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/parse_url.html):

> Returns a JSON object consisting of all the components (fragment, host, path, port, query, scheme) in a valid input URL/URI.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT CONCAT('http://', COLUMN1) AS URL
  FROM VALUES   ('www.url1.com/test'), 
                ('www.url1.com/test2/'), 
                ('www.url1.com/test/sub_test/')
)
SELECT URL, 
       PARSE_URL(URL) AS parts,
       PARSE_URL(URL):path::text AS path,
       TRIM(PARSE_URL(URL):path::text, '/') AS path
FROM cte;
```

Output:

[image]

---

EDIT:

> *How would you get just "sub_test" for the last example you have there?*

`SPLIT_PART` with negative index could be used:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT CONCAT('http://', COLUMN1) AS URL
  FROM VALUES   ('www.url1.com/test'),
                ('www.url1.com/test2/'), 
                ('www.url1.com/test/sub_test/')
)
SELECT URL, 
       PARSE_URL(URL) AS parts,
       PARSE_URL(URL):path::text AS path,
       SPLIT_PART(TRIM(PARSE_URL(URL):path::text, '/'), '/', -1) AS path3
FROM cte;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Lukasz. How would you get just "sub_test" for the last example you have there?

Answer (score 2):

You can just trim off the final slash like this:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(trim(URL, '/'), '/([^/]+)$', 1, 1, 'e', 1) as URL_EXTRACT
```

Parsing the URL to a JSON as Lukasz showed will cover many more possibilities, but this will be faster for large data sets if this is the only problem to correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Positive Lookahead for this task:

```
[^\/\n]+(?=\/?$)
```

Explanation:

- `[^\/\n]+`: any combination of characters other than slash and new line (your match)
- `(?=\/?$)`: positive lookahead (checks if after your match there's)

  - `\/?`: optional slash
  - `$`: end string

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/IneP65/1).

Comment: Snowflake does not support lookaheads except by using UDFs.